# Ask for suggestions on how to write LaTeX faster?

Tags: editors, ide

I need to type a large number of math equations but find that my typing of the formulas is much slower than writing, which cost me a lot of time every day. Any tips about how to speed up?

Another thing is that although the generated file is enjoyable to read, but when I want to modify part of the equations, I feel frustrated looking into the messy source code. How can I write the LaTeX neatly?

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: your question is very unclear (and could be closed as "opinion based") but you have tagged it as markdown and say  "LaTeX, overleaf, Markdown" but markdown is not normally involved in latex documents or overleaf. Are you asking about writing TeX documents or markdown?

Comment: (1) Try LyX. For math is nearly a WYSIWYG environment. (2) Try Rstudio, that allow pop-up previews of LaTeX formulas in RMarkdown.  (3) Try a LaTeX editor with live preview (e.g.: Gummi ) (4) Try a LaTeX editor  that supports source/preview synchronization (e.g., TeXworks).  (5) Get used to math commands also help.

Comment: @Fran LyX is exactly what I want! Thank you so much!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry for the vague expression. I shouldn't mention Markdown and have modified the question to make it clear. Thanks.

Comment: @ying I changed the tags of your question to `ide` and `editors`, which seems to be what you're after. `latex3` is for questions regarding the LaTeX3 project, which is not what you want here

Comment: Oh, thank you so much!@PhelypeOleinik

Comment: Emacs integrates a symbolic calculator which allows to perform complex calculations. You perform (or not) the calculations in the usual algebraic syntax and the Emacs calculator displays the result in LaTeX syntax. It also has an editor of tables allowing in particular the insertion or the displacement of columns in an extremely fast way, and many other features which make it possible to save much time. preview latex lets you see the rendering of math expressions

Comment: @gigiairg Thank you for the suggestion! I'll try it :-)